# Ubuntu Wifi cannot see neither connect to 5Ghz hotspot

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-21.10

I would ask if anyone had a clue about an issue with Wi-Fi on Ubuntu.

So the thing is on Windows I can connect to my 5ghz hotspot (On channel 100), but since I've installed Ubuntu (with exactly the same hardware), I'm not even able to see the access point, I've checked my Wi-Fi configuration, and it seems that I'm not able to use the Channel 100, but ... why do I am allowed to do it on Windows but not on Ubuntu ?

Does anyone have a clue about my issue ?

```
wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 32 : 5.16 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 50 : 5.25 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 66 : 5.33 GHz
          Channel 68 : 5.34 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
```

Comment: Channels above 48 have different international limitations - check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_(802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax)

Comment: I've already tried the technic described [here](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/wifi#autorisation_du_canal) (sorry it's French, but the commands still the same), as French user I've set it up to FR but still the same issue the Wi-Fi channel is still unavailable.